# CASL render child component if 'cannot'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authorization, casl

How do I display a child component with `@casl/react` if a user 'cannot' do something?

I'm asking this question because I still want to render a component if the user isn't authorized, but in a disabled state.

Example:

What I want to do:

```
<Cannot do="update" on="style">
    <button disabled={true}> Update </button>
</Cannot>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Can>` supports `not` prop:

`<Can not do="update" on="style">...</Can>`

https://github.com/stalniy/casl/blob/master/packages/casl-react/README.md#3-property-names-and-aliases

Answer (score 0):

Forgot I can just check the abilities

`<button disabled={!abilities.can('update', 'style')}> Update </button>`

Comment: This is a wrong solution, it can be changed on the client side and not secure